# Group data and assign group id based on time intervals in R

Tags: r, timestamp, tidyverse

I am trying to figure out how to assign group id based on time intervals in R.

More context: I have merged GPS data (lat/lon data points, recorded in irregular intervals) with acceleration data (ACC "bursts" of 82 data points, recorded at the start of every minute - all 82 data points in one burst have the same timestamp).

As GPS points and ACC bursts were collected simultaneously, I now want to group GPS points with the associated ACC bursts: assign all GPS and ACC data that *ocurr within the same minute*, a unique group id.

EDIT: Here are some sample data. I want to group the GPS point in row 8 to the ACC data within the same minute (in this case above the GPS point).

```
structure(list(X.1 = 1:11, timestamp = c("2019-01-26T16:25:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:25:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:25:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:25:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:25:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:25:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:25:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:25:47Z", "2019-01-26T16:26:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:26:00Z", "2019-01-26T16:26:00Z"), sensor.type = c("acceleration", "acceleration", "acceleration", "acceleration", "acceleration", "acceleration", "acceleration", "gps", "acceleration", "acceleration", "acceleration"), location.long = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44.4777343, NA, NA, NA), location.lat = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -12.2839707, NA, NA, NA), annotation = c("Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing", "Moving/Climbing"), X = c(2219L, 1694L, 1976L, 1744L, 2014L, 2202L, 2269L, NA, 1874L, 2024L, 1990L), Y = c(1416L, 1581L, 1524L, 1620L, 1409L, 1545L, 1771L, NA, 1687L, 1773L, 1813L), Z = c(2189L, 2209L, 2121L, 2278L, 2003L, 2034L, 2060L, NA, 2431L, 2504L, 2428L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

X.1            timestamp    sensor.type     location.long   location.lat annotation   X    Y    Z
1    1 2019-01-26T16:25:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2219 1416 2189        
2    2 2019-01-26T16:25:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1694 1581 2209       
3    3 2019-01-26T16:25:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1976 1524 2121       
4    4 2019-01-26T16:25:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1744 1620 2278       
5    5 2019-01-26T16:25:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2014 1409 2003        
6    6 2019-01-26T16:25:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2202 1545 2034       
7    7 2019-01-26T16:25:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2269 1771 2060       
8    8 2019-01-26T16:25:47Z gps               44.47773    -12.28397 Moving/Climbing   NA   NA   NA
9    9 2019-01-26T16:26:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1874 1687 2431        
10  10 2019-01-26T16:26:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2024 1773 2504       
11  11 2019-01-26T16:26:00Z acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1990 1813 2428
```

Does that make sense? I know *lubridate* can summarize data based on time intervals but how do I add a new group id (variable) based on timestamps?

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data in a copy/pasteable format. `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` is perfect for the first 10 rows. Choose a suitable small subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I added some sample data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. We convert your `timestamp` column to a proper datetime class, add a new column rounding down to the nearest minute, and then create an ID based on the rounded timestamp:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat %>% 
  mutate(
    timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp),
    minute = floor_date(timestamp, unit = "minute"),
    group_id = as.integer(factor(minute))
  )
  
#    X.1           timestamp  sensor.type location.long location.lat      annotation    X    Y    Z
# 1    1 2019-01-26 16:25:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2219 1416 2189
# 2    2 2019-01-26 16:25:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1694 1581 2209
# 3    3 2019-01-26 16:25:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1976 1524 2121
# 4    4 2019-01-26 16:25:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1744 1620 2278
# 5    5 2019-01-26 16:25:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2014 1409 2003
# 6    6 2019-01-26 16:25:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2202 1545 2034
# 7    7 2019-01-26 16:25:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2269 1771 2060
# 8    8 2019-01-26 16:25:47          gps      44.47773    -12.28397 Moving/Climbing   NA   NA   NA
# 9    9 2019-01-26 16:26:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1874 1687 2431
# 10  10 2019-01-26 16:26:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 2024 1773 2504
# 11  11 2019-01-26 16:26:00 acceleration            NA           NA Moving/Climbing 1990 1813 2428
#                 minute group_id
# 1  2019-01-26 16:25:00        1
# 2  2019-01-26 16:25:00        1
# 3  2019-01-26 16:25:00        1
# 4  2019-01-26 16:25:00        1
# 5  2019-01-26 16:25:00        1
# 6  2019-01-26 16:25:00        1
# 7  2019-01-26 16:25:00        1
# 8  2019-01-26 16:25:00        1
# 9  2019-01-26 16:26:00        2
# 10 2019-01-26 16:26:00        2
# 11 2019-01-26 16:26:00        2
```

Comment: @IsMa Glad to hear it! In that case, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark in the left margin next to the voting buttons.